# dynamic filters in ssrs to let user enter values

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012

I have a report which displays Activity, product, Customer etc values. I need to provide filters (textboxes) so that the user entries values to it and based on that the rows get filtered(after refresh). Is this possible to achieve in ssrs. If yes, please help with how

Answer (score 0):

Refer below links for SSRS :

http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2013/09/ssrs-how-to-add-input-parameters-in.html

https://romiller.com/2008/07/29/searchable-dependant-parameters-in-ssrs/

Comment: I am using basic rdlc report provided by visual studio and it doesn't have all options as shown in that link.

Comment: You need full version of Sql Server and BIDS for report development.

Answer (score 0):

Local reports (RDLC) don't have the parameter bar. But you can make your own controls on the page to get the parameter values, and then use code to pass those in to your local report.

Googling RDLC parameter gives lots of advice, for example this video which shows how to do it:

[How to create RDLC report with parameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=859BmmVOm8M)